# How to remove process.env.NODE_ENV from vite's production bundle and delete unused code

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, rollup, esbuild

During a migration from webpack to vite, we were using `process.env.NODE_ENV` to add specific code.

Now using vite, the bundle includes every thing meant to be in development mode, include `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

[image]

Here is the `vite.config.js`:

```
import path from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

/**
 * @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
 */
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
  console.log('vite configuration for mode', mode);
  return {
    define: {
      NODE_ENV: "production",
    },
    build: {
      mode: "development",
      lib: {
        name: 'MyLib',
        fileName: 'mylib.production',
        entry: path.join(process.cwd(), "src/index.ts"),
      },
      rollupOptions: {
        external: 'react',
        output: [
          {
            format: 'umd',
            globals: { react: 'react' },
            entryFileNames: `mylib.production.js`,
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

How to eliminate `process.env.NODE_ENV` and the unused code from the bundle ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this help? https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define

Comment: I believe I am already using it

Comment: I think it should be `process.env.NODE_ENV` not `NODE_ENV`.

Comment: fixed via the replace plugin

Answer (score 7):

You need to define `process.env.NODE_ENV` as following:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html

> Environment Variables
>
> .... If this is undesirable, you can use define: {
> 'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"' } for example to statically
> replace them.

(be careful of the quotation marks), or for example:

```
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    define: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
    },
  }
})
```

.

Comment: Just a note that this is true when Vite is used in "library" mode, which seems to be the case of the OP. In normal client-app builds process.env.NODE_ENV will be be properly replaced on build time withount any additional configuration. It's written good in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Fixed via the `replace` plugin:

```
const replace = require('@rollup/plugin-replace');
// or import replace form '@rollup/plugin-replace';

// in plugins section:
replace({
  preventAssignment: true,
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
}),
```